# Difficulty on understanding conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have some confusion when understanding the concept of conditional probability.

1. Given any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and any two constants $m$ and $k$, Is it true that $$P(Y-X=m | Y > X) = P(Y = m+k | Y > k)? $$

   My guess is it is not always true,
   because
   $$\begin{align*}
   P(Y-X=m | Y > X) & = \sum_{k} P(Y-X=m, X=k | Y > X) \\
   & = \sum_{k}  P(Y-X=m | X=k, Y > X) P(X=k | Y > X) \\
   & = \sum_{k}  P(Y-k=m | Y > k) P(X=k | Y > X).
   \end{align*}$$
2. What if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d.?
   Even further, how about when $X$ and $Y$
   are i.i.d. with some memoryless
   distribution, i.e. exponential or
   geometric distribution?

   In [my previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26386/questions-about-geometric-distribution) under the
   setting of  $X$ and $Y$ being i.i.d.
   with geometric distribution, [Henry
   wrote](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26386/questions-about-geometric-distribution/26412#26412) $$P(Y-X=m | Y > X) = P(Y = m+k
   | Y > k),$$ about which he said in his comment it is true because  "$k$ is
   merely shorthand for" $X$. But I
   still don't quite understand that yet.
3. If Y is a random variable subject to
   a memoryless distribution, i.e.
   exponential or geometric
   distribution and X is any other
   random variable with any
   distribution, is it true that
   $$P(Y>X+m | Y > X) = P(Y > m)$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know how to show the long formula properly. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Also is it possible to link to a comment? For example, the second comment after this reply http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26386/questions-about-geometric-distribution/26412#26412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Other readers should follow the links to see the context.  $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables taking values on the positive integers)

1. No they are not true in general.
2. What is true, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, is 
   $$Pr(Y-X=m | Y > X, X=k) = Pr(Y = m+k | Y > k) $$
3. If $Y$ is memoryless (i.e. geometric) then $Pr(Y=m+k | Y > k) = Pr(Y = m) $, so if $X$ and $Y$ are independent 
   $$Pr(Y=m+X | Y > X, X = k) = Pr(Y = m) $$
   and since that is true for all $k$
   $$Pr(Y-X=m | Y > X) = Pr(Y = m) $$

Comment: Thanks! I should mention that m and k are nonnegative constants. In Part 3, (1) I was wondering if it is true when X is any random variable, not necessarily independent with Y? $$\begin{align*}
P(Y-X=m | Y > X) & = \sum_{k} P(Y-X=m, X=k | Y > X) \\
& = \sum_{k}  P(Y-X=m | X=k, Y > X) P(X=k | Y > X) \\
& = \sum_{k}  P(Y-k=m | Y > k) P(X=k | Y > X).
\end{align*}$$ If $P(Y-k=m | Y > k)=P(Y=m)$, then the above becomes $\sum_{k}  P(Y-k=m | Y > k) P(X=k | Y > X) = P(Y=m)  \sum_{k}  P(X=k | Y > X) = P(Y=m)$? (2) Is the same conclusion true for exponential distribution?

Comment: Are you sure you can say $P(Y-X=m | X=k, Y > X) = P(Y-k=m | Y > k)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent? Suppose $X$ is $1,2,3,4$ with equal probability and $Y= X \pm 1$ with equal probability. Then let $m=1$ and $k=2$.  We have $P(Y-X=1 | X=2, Y > X) = 1$ since the only possibility given $X=2$ and $Y > X$ is $(2,3)$.  But $P(Y-2=1 | Y > 2) = 1/2$ since the possibilities given $Y > 2$ are $(2,3)$, $(3,4)$, $(4,5)$ and $(4,3)$ and only when $Y=3$ do we have $Y-2=1$.